# How to get an automatic space which is repeat after 4 digits form an input field by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the input field of the card number :

```
<input type="text" id="input-number" placeholder="e.g 1234 5678 9123 0000">
```

I want when a customer enters the 16 digits of the card number it will be displayed like a placeholder a space after 4 digits.

How can it be achieved?

Comment: so what you're describing is called an input mask. what have you tried?

Comment: @DerekPollard I have tried many masking options but now working. Which masking option do you recommend?

Comment: @DerekPollard ``` <input type="text" id="input-number" data-grouplength="4" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="e.g 1234 5678 9123 0000"> ``` I have tried this but not working.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your *attempted* code, there are a couple of things to go over.

### The `pattern` Attribute

The `pattern` attribute is actually used for form validation, rather than an input mask (*which seems to be what you are asking for*). So you could use the `pattern` attribute to have your form validate the field once it is submitted, but it will not alter the value displayed in that field.

### `data` Attributes

`data` attributes (such as `data-grouplength`) are essentially custom attributes you can set on elements. This allows you to store or associate custom data/information with an element. In this case, it seems to be a custom `data` attribute for a group length of 4 (grouping the value in sets of 4). But `data` attributes by themself do nothing. They just store a value which can be used by something like JavaScript.

### Input Masking

To achieve your desired result, you essentially want to take the value in your input and alter it to fit a specific format. This is where you will filter out any non-numeric values and group the value in sets of 4. I like to do this with an event listener on the `input` event, so it happens as the user types (`keyup` or `keydown` *could* work here, but I think `input` works well enough). We can also pull in the custom `data` attribute for group length here. Lastly, we just want a basic regular expression to only accept digits.

```js
document.querySelector("#input-number").addEventListener("input", e => {
  let r = new RegExp(`[0-9]{1,${e.target.dataset.grouplength}}`, "g");
  e.target.value = (e.target.value.match(r)) ? e.target.value.match(r).join(" "): "";
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-number" data-grouplength=4 placeholder="e.g 1234 5678 9123 0000">
```

### UPDATE

Following up on a comment, I've added a new snippet with updated code. This allows for a **maxlength** `data` attribute (*yes I know HTML inputs have a native `maxlength` attribute*), and it also preserves the carret position.

```js
document.querySelector("#input-number").addEventListener("input", e => {
  let v = e.target.value.replaceAll(/[^0-9]/g, ""),
      r = new RegExp(`.{1,${e.target.dataset.grouplength}}`, "g"),
      s = e.target.selectionStart,
      d = e.target.selectionEnd,
      fixCarret = (d < e.target.value.length) ? true : false;
  e.target.value = (v.match(r)) ? v.match(r).slice(0, e.target.dataset.maxlength/e.target.dataset.grouplength).join(" "): "";
  if(fixCarret) e.target.setSelectionRange(s, d);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-number" data-grouplength=4 data-maxlength=16 placeholder="e.g 1234 5678 9123 0000">
```

**NOTE**

I would like to note that because of the way this code filters values longer than the max length, it *pushes* characters at the end of the string. Essentially, if you already have 16 characters and you type a new number in the 2nd character position, the number in position 16 is removed and all numbers after the 2nd position are shifted down. This may or may not be desirable, depending on the situation.

Comment: This solution does not maintain the correct caret position when editing and also allows the user to enter more digits than required.  Yet, it does provide a starting point. +1

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it.

Run the following function on input.

```
function formatCardNumber() {
var cardNumber = document.getElementById("cardNumber");
var value = cardNumber.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
var formattedValue = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    if (i % 4 == 0 && i > 0) {
      formattedValue += " ";
    }
    formattedValue += value[i];
  }
  cardNumber.value = formattedValue;
```

}

Your input will look like this.

```
<input type="text" name="cardNumber" id="cardNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="1234 5678 9012 3456" maxlength="20" oninput="formatCardNumber()"
```